# Finding inverse of $2\mod 127$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I can't seem to understand why the inverse of $2 \mod 127=64$

I used the Euclidean algorithm:

$2x=1 \mod127$

$127=63\cdot 2+1$

$1=127-63\cdot 2 \mod127$

$x=63$?

I'm pretty sure it's a really stupid error....please help!

Comment: You forgot the minus.

Comment: As quid indicated, one solution is $-63$.  If you add $127$ to $-63$, you will obtain the residue $64$.  $2^{-1} \equiv 64 \pmod{127}$ since $2 \cdot 64 \equiv 128 \equiv 1 \pmod{127}$.  The set of all inverses is $64 + 127n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The solution you found corresponds to the choice $n = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

$2\times 64=128\equiv 1\mod (127)$

Answer (score 0):

More simply: $\ {\rm mod}\ m = 2n\!-\!1\!:\,\ 2n\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{-1}\equiv n\equiv (m\!+\!1)/2\,\ $ [$\equiv (127\!+\!1)/2\equiv 64$ ]

**Remark** $\ $ The [same idea works](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1146117/242) to compute $\, a^{-1}\!\pmod{an\pm1},\,$ i.e. when $\,m \equiv \pm1\pmod{a}$. This will often be simpler than using the Extended Euclidean algorithm, so may help to avoid errors, such as your omitting the sign on $\,63.$